# Python Wget?/Scripting books?

Tags: python, scripting

I've been learning python here recently....mainly for scripting purposes....since apparently it's supposed to be almost as good as bash for doing small script jobs.

But two questions, Does python have it's own sort of "wget" or do you have to use a library for that (or does it have one built in?) for stuff such as retrieving images off a website for instance.

Secondly....is there a book, or online resource that mainly teaches python from a "scripting" point of view. Since as far as High level languages go....i mostly use C/C#/C++, but I really need a decent scripting language, and it seems Perl has gone out of style from what everyones told me.

Thanks

Comment: "do you have to use a library for that"?  The answer -- in Python -- is always "yes".  However the library is built-in.  So.  It's not clear what you're asking there.  Perhaps you should break this into two questions.  And search for "wget" before asking, since that's been asked.  And search for books, since that's been asked, too.

Comment: "PERL has gone out of style from what everyones told me." - you may want to talk to people who are NOT Python people to get a less biased advice :)

Comment: "apparently it's supposed to be almost as good as bash" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do. Python offers you access to wget just like bash. You can call your normal wget command and retrieve a simple file using e.g. `os.system`.

However, depending on how much power you require, Python offers you much more flexibility with additional packages. You may want to take a look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for an example of a more powerful 'wget'. Or simply `urllib` if you need a different protocol supported.

As for the second part of your question: I haven't read any books specifically for scripting, but a quick google search reveals that there's more than enough of them available.

If you have experience with scripting (bash or perl) though, I suggest you just follow the normal python tutorial and maybe skip the more object-oriented parts. Anyways, python is a language that can be learned and applied very fast.

Comment: So I guess with python I better get used to using a ton of libraries? Hmmm I was always used to built in stuff. Lol

Comment: @Sauron: The libraries are "built-in".  They came with your Python download.

Comment: Oh ok gotcha, I thought you meant I would be using like....third party stuff. NM lol

Answer (score 2):

you can do an HTTP GET request using urllib2 like this:

```
import urllib2
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
print resp.read()
```

for Python 2.x, have a look at:

- [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) (in the standard library)
- [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (in the standard library)
- [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) (in the standard library)
- [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) (in the standard library, for making calls to wget directly)
- [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) (3rd party http module)
- [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) (3rd party binding to curl)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the first question.  You'll want to use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).  There are a bunch of different [internet protocol handling libraries](http://docs.python.org/library/internet.html) built in.